# Access to this.props.navigation on Header Component

Tags: react-native

I have an ApplicationHeader Component and I want to navigate to a specific screen on touch, but I'm getting

> undefined is not an object (evaluating this.props.navigation.navigate)

**App.js**

```js
render() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView forceInset={{ bottom: 'never' }} style={styles.container}>
      {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <StatusBar barStyle="default" />}
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ApplicationHeader navigation={this.props.navigation} />
        <AppNavigator />
      </Provider>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

**ApplicationHeader.js**

```js
class ApplicationHeader extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  openWishlist() {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Wishlist')
  }

  render() {
    const { isLogged } = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={AppStyle.header}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.openWishlist()}>
          {!isLogged && (<Image source={imgWishList} style={AppStyle.headerWishlist} />)}
          {isLogged && (<Image source={imgWishListLogged} style={AppStyle.headerWishlist} />)}
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ApplicationHeader);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like that your HeaderComponent is might not be in Navigation Stack.

In that case, you can try the following solution:

First import `withNavigation` in your file like

```
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';
```

After that change your component export to

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(withNavigation(ApplicationHeader));
```

So you will get the access to navigation pros in this component.

Also your ApplicationHeader can move to inner container components. It shouldn't have to be in App.js to use the navigation props.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I tried but I got **withnavigation can only be used on a view hierarchy of a navigator**

Comment: Yes, I have updated my answer you have to move your ApplicationHeader to any Screen component because in App.js will not have the navigation props.as it is not  lies in AppNavigator.

Comment: Thanks, I moved my ApplicationHeader to **Homepage.js** and it worked. Need I to add `<ApplicationHeader/>` to all screen files with this approach or there's a better solution?

Comment: Glad to hear that, if worked you can accept the answer.